# Programmatically opening a popup in a Mapbox map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a mapbox map at http://bei.dev.bclcmaps.com/ which has popups that open when clicking a marker.

My problem is that I need a way to set a default popup to be open on page load based on a value in the URL. This can be a latitude and longitude or some other value, whatever's easiest.

I have banged on this for a while and it seems like I either need to:

1. Programmatically open a popup via the Mapbox JS API, which I can't figure out since it seems that my popups are auto-generated on the fly when a marker is clicked, or
2. Programmatically click a marker to open its popup. I can't figure this out because 1) I don't know how to find a marker by lat/lon and 2) I can't figure out how to click a marker with JS.

I've tried this:

```
map.gridLayer.fire('click', {latLng: L.latLng(28.04419, -81.947864)});
```

which closes any existing open popups but doesn't seem to open its own. I've also tried digging through the map and the leaflet objects to see if location/marker data is stored in there and I can't find anything besides the tiles.

Most of the examples I can find seem to be using GeoJSON which I'm not using so that makes things difficult.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you share some sample code? I've never used Leaflet before, but it can't be any worse than debugging/extending OpenLayers *shudder*. Maybe this is an easy one for Mapbox/Leaflet expersts, otherwise I'd be happy to take a shot at this with a little more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map.fireEvent('click', {latlng: L.latLng(28.04419, -81.947864)});
```

You were close - the 'click' event needs a latLng object named 'latlng' (lower case)

Comment: or `map.fire('click', { latLng: coords, point: map.project(coords), originalEvent: {} })` - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5060

Answer (score 1):

For mapbox gl you can currently use
`map.fire('click', [-118.3214,34.0318])`

but it may be deprecated in the future https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0450

Comment: then how can we do ?